# Linqpad error: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, linqpad

For some reason, I'm getting the error `String or binary data would be truncated` when attempting to put one of the input parameters into a temp table. Does anyone know why?

```
--Psuedo-Trans Table--

DECLARE @item nvarchar(50)       = '511010200'

--Drop temp table
IF object_id('TempDB..#parameters') IS NOT NULL

    DROP Table #parameters

CREATE TABLE #parameters(

   item varchar

)

insert into #parameters
(item)
values (@item)

select * from #parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

When declare `varchar(n)`,if length `n` is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.

so you'd better to change `item varchar` to `item varchar(50)`.

BUT please note your `@item` is `nvarchar`, will be double the length of the `varchar`, meaning you need to declare the `varchar(18)` at least to store your example data. Just in case any data larger than your example, you'd better to declare 2x the size of the maximum of `@item`. or the easiest way is to `item nvarchar(50)`

Comment: the `create table` part